# emberjs itemcontroller property scope

Tags: ember.js

I need an explanation for the usage of an itemcontroller in emberJS.

I created a handlebars template that looks like this:

```
{{#each thing in controller itemController="itemController"}}

  {{view "testview" contentBinding="thing"}}

{{/each}}
```

The testview creates a html table and within the testview I use a second view in a each loop which creates several tr:

```
{{each item in view.content.thing}}

  {{view 'trview' contentBinding="item"}}

{{/each}}
```

In addition to that I added a property "listOfProperties" (Ember.A()) to the itemController.

I use the click function of the trview to add a value to the "listOfProperties" array of the itemController.

And here I receive an error: If I click on a tr, the value is added to each itemControllers "listOfProperties" array and not only to one "things" itemController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess since you didn't include your item controller, but it's likely you're running into a reference issue.  Array's are a reference and as such are shared across instances of item controllers.

```
App.ItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  setup: function(){
    this.set('listOfProperties', []);
  }.on('init'),
  listOfProperties: null,
});
```